# Testing a sample is drawn from a mixture

Tags: mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

Suppose you have data $(Y_1, \dots, Y_N)$ drawn from a finite mixture population with $K$ components and you estimate the model parameters $(\theta_1,\dots, \theta_K)$ and the mixture weights $(\phi_1, \dots, \phi_K)$. I am interested in cases where $Y_i$ is a vector containing a finite number of measurements for the same unit (say $T$ time observations) and measurements are discrete random variables.

I want to test whether a new random draw $(Y_1, \dots, Y_N)$ was generated by the same model vs. the alternative it was generated from a different mixture. The alternative might be framed as as the same mixture model above with $K$ components and parameters $(\theta_1,\dots, \theta_K)$ but different weights $(\phi_1, \dots, \phi_K)$ or a more general alternative, but I am not sure how far this can go.

Comment: Some more context might be useful. What kind of data do you have? Why do you want to test if it's drawn from the same mixture?

Comment: Please see the edited question @Xi'an

Comment: @LouisCialdella I am thinking of it as an specification test of the model, I added more context to the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to ignore that the assumed distributions are mixtures, and just treat the marginal distributions of the data as arbitrary discrete distributions. You could then use any method to test whether two samples of discrete data are from the same population. For instance, a Chi-square test for homogeneity.

Another option might be an extension of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for discrete distributions. I don't think there is one for the two sample case, only for comparing a discrete empirical distribution to a theoretical (assumed known) distribution. So you could use the estimated first mixture model as defining the theoretical distribution, and then test whether the new sample comes from this distribution. The `ks.test` function of the `dgof` package for R should provide this test (see e.g. https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-2/RJournal_2011-2_Arnold+Emerson.pdf). A downside of this option is that assuming an estimated model is identical to the population distribution will bias the test results.

Another option could be to use a likelihood ratio test, comparing a general model in which you allow the mixture weights ($\phi_i$), and any other relevant parameters ($\theta_i$) to depend on the sample, to a nested model where you restrict these parameters to be identical over the samples. If you allow all parameters to vary over the two samples, this is quite straightforward (estimating two separate $K$-component mixtures for each sample vs estimating a single $K$-component mixture for both samples). Varying only mixture weights is also relatively easy. Using `R`, you can apply equality constraints in the `fit` function to a `mix` function in `depmixS4`.

Which method will work best will depend on various things, such as the size of the two samples. You could try simulation to assess the relative power of the options.